# document.getElementById vs jQuery $html() to receive Server-sent Event Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, server-sent-events

I'm testing to receive data with SSE

This is my stream.php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$time = date('r');
echo "data: test\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

To receive data I use:

```
var source=new EventSource("stream.php");
    source.onmessage=function(e)
    {
      //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=e.data + "<br/>";
        $("#result").html(e.data);
    };
```

When I use `document.getElementById("result")`, it show the data repeatedly. But when I use `$("#result").html(e.data)`, it doesn't. Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.innerHTML +=` adds to the already exsisting HTML, note the `+=`, while jQuery's `html()` method overwrites the HTML every time.

jQuery has several other methods that adds to the existing markup, like `append()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the vanila script `+=e.data` you are appending the new content to the existing markup, but `.html()` overrides the existing values.

```
$("#result").append(e.data + '<br/>')
```

or

```
$("#result").html(function(_, html){
    return html += e.data + '<br/>';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+=` in `.innerHTML+=` is appending the content to the existing content. That would be equivalent to `$("#result").html($("#result").html() + e.data);`